# Is it possible to set up a custom field that requires a specific format eg xx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx

Tags: custom-fields

We need to store bank account numbers and will set up a CiviCRM custom field for the data. Ideally we would like the field to be such that people only enter data in the following format xx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx. Is it possible to customise the custom field format? if so how would I do it?

Or do I need to create a work around eg have 4 integer fields that display inline with dashes inbetween.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest adding a javascript formatter to a single, custom input text field. I haven't tried it, but [formatter.js](https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js) looks like it would deliver what you want.

Their [Credit Card demo](http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/demos.html) illustrates what you want - accepts pasting of data with and without hyphens, prevents pasting / input of values which don't match the validation rule. It just needs a different pattern for hyphen placement to deliver bank accounts.